# Can't make Apple Sign In work with Xamarin.Essentials

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I know this might not be the best question, not much information, but I will try.

I'm trying to add Apple Sign In to Xamarin.Forms app using Xamarin.Essentials. As of now, I'm just trying to make it work on iOS 13, without going any further yet, server side is not required as I understand for this limited scope.

I looked into the sample app for Xamarin.Essentials, and came to conclusion that specifically for iOS 13 it would be enough to call

```
            await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync();
```

However, I got an exception "com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000". Couldn't fine more details.

Then I took Xamarin.Essentials sample app, changed Bundle Id to what I have in my app, and then it worked. This validated that certificates and App store were configured correctly.

I tried to get Xamarin.Essentials from GitHub and debug through the library, the exception is in AppleSignInAuthenticator.ios.cs in "PlatformAuthenticateAsync", at the line

```
        var creds = await authManager.Credentials;
```

Update: In entitlements.plist I added

```
<key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
<array>
    <string>Default</string>
</array>
```

Any help or advise is appreciated.

Comment: Have you selected "Apple Sign-in" in the app's entitlements?

Comment: have you read the docs where it says "To add Apple Sign In to your apps, first you'll need to configure your app to use Apple Sign In."?

Comment: I have this in Entitlements:
 <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
 <array>
  <string>Default</string>
 </array>

Comment: Can you try to create a new project and set up step by step to see if it works? I think what you did is enough to enable Apple Sign In.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing, and simple app worked. So, now I'm trying to add all other things I already have one by one to see what will break it. It's obviously something in my existing app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I new it would be something stupid.

I have Entitlements.Development.plist and Entitlements.Production.plist. Should I say more (didn't add key for *com.apple.developer.applesignin* everywhere).

BTW, how people handle it, to have separate value for key *aps-environment* between development and production?

Comment: Why do you have two Entitlements.plists in your project? One is enough and it work under both development and production.

Comment: Also, you can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: The reason I created two Entitlements.plist is different value for aps-environment key. I stole it from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015434/116317. What is the better way?

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Then the key should be `add key for com.apple.developer.applesignin everywhere. `

Comment: Can you please mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).